# Word for "person with a wish"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say someone has been accepted by the Make-A-Wish foundation. Before entering the process of having the wish, the person is called an applicant. How about after his or her wish has been accepted by the foundation?

Comment: A "participant"?

Comment: Please see  [this guidance from Stack Exchange Management](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity) about such questions. We are not a word-puzzle and crossword puzzle site; we're a site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English-language enthusiasts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Admittee** describes such a person.

From [Webster’s](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/admittee):

> :a person who is allowed to enter a place (such as a college or
> university) :a person who is admitted
>
> But the college can’t know
> :a person who is allowed to enter a place (such as a college or
> university) :a person who is admitted.
> Worse, it can’t know which ones. In putting together its **admittee** list
> it took great pains to strike a balance—men and women, athletes and
> musicians, black and white, rich and poor. —James Fallows,  The
> Atlantic,  November 2003

The most common way I have read colleges and institutions referring such people is simply as “admitted candidates” or “admitted students”.